# how do I set an ssh password

Tags: ssh, passwords

I see the following line in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I assume if I remove the hash and make the line read

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

that I will be able to ssh to my server with a password. But how do I actually set the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer as your question is unclear as to whether your want an existing user account to be able to SSH.

The password you would use would be for the user account you would log on to the host. So if you had a user account named **mylocalaccount** and you have set it up for ssh access then you would use whatever password you normally use for **mylocalaccount**